# Uncaught Error: This Firebase project requires import into Google Cloud Platform to resume service

Tags: firebase, webrtc, simplewebrtc, openwebrtc, openwebrtcdemo

Getting this Uncaught Error: This Firebase project requires import into Google Cloud Platform to resume service. 
When I am trying to conference video call through Webrtc.

I got this url- https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web#import_your_project_to_the_firebase_console

but I don't want to upload my project on cloud.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution.
Go to this url https://console.firebase.google.com/ and login as gmail account.
Click on "Add Project"
You will get page like this
[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9jXI.png)

After that you'll get your created project like this
[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw8mG.png)

Now click on project.You'll redirect to firebase project overview page.Click on "Add Firebase to your web app".
[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ6aE.png)

You'll get this code

apiKey: "******************************", 
authDomain: "****-****",
databaseURL: "****-****",
projectId: "****-****",
storageBucket: "****-*****",
messagingSenderId: "************"

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EmLE.png)

Copy databaseURL and replace with your webrtc code where firebase url or code is define.

You may get like this in webrtc code

openSocket: function(config) {
            var channel = config.channel || location.href.replace( //|:|#|%|.|[|]/g , '');
            var socket = new Firebase('####-####' + channel);
            socket.channel = channel;
            socket.on("child_added", function(data) {
                config.onmessage && config.onmessage(data.val());
            });
            socket.send = function(data) {
                this.push(data);
            };
            config.onopen && setTimeout(config.onopen, 1);
            socket.onDisconnect().remove();
            return socket;
        }

Replace
var socket = new Firebase('####-#####' + channel);

to

var socket = new Firebase('****databaseURL****' + channel);

Please Remove **** in ''

Now Click on Database option which is placed in left side and select "Realtime Database"

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BUON.png)

Now Click on "Rules" Tab and change the "Read Write" value.Both value should "true".
[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mujXi.png)

Now Check your webrtc consultation.This will run without firebase error.