# Auth error - This Firebase project requires import into Google Cloud Platform to resume service

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Recently tried to start up a new project in my firebase console, to allow another developer to run an instance of our app.  The web based SPA-style app is written using Firebase 2.0.  Using authwithpassword, I get back an error “This Firebase project requires import into Google Cloud Platform to resume service.“.

As far as I can tell, the project does exist in my cloud platform console.  Any ideas?  Is this a usage limit error?

There was another question out there on this error message, but that related to a user who specifically did not want to place a project on the cloud servers.  In this case, the error message is displaying even though the project is already managed on Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught Error: This Firebase project requires import into Google Cloud Platform to resume service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938229/uncaught-error-this-firebase-project-requires-import-into-google-cloud-platform)

Comment: First feedback from Firebase support suggests that new projects created in the console will generate errors when called with the now-deprecated Firebase 2 API.